# Double brace initialization with new?

Tags: c++

Hello just wondering is it possible in C++03 to do something as following. I have tried it but doesn't work for me.

```
struct SomeClass{
int a,b,c,d;
};

SomeClass * temp  = new SomeClass();
*temp = { 1,2,3,4};
```

I did it but compiler gives me a warning that extended initalizers are only supported with C++11
Is there some other way to use double brace initalization when using new to create the object?
Constructors are not allowed

Comment: Double brace initialization is a Java term. What you want is an initializer. Also I don't think it's possible before C++11

Comment: Do you really have to use `new` at all? Do you really have to use a compiler that does not support (parts of) C++11?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do this directly in C++03, but you can (perhaps) simplify the job compared to just brute force, with something you might think of as an "out of class constructor":

```
struct someclass{
    int a, b, c, d;
};

someclass make(int a, int b, int c, int d) { 
    someclass ret = {a, b, c, d};
    return ret;
}

int main(){
    someclass *s = new someclass();

    *s = make(1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

It's a pretty easy bet that any reasonably recent (and probably even most pretty old) C++ compiler will inline the function call, so the function call won't impose any overhead. If you wanted to, you could also turn the function into a template, and overload it for different numbers of parameters, so you could do things like:

```
someclass *s = new someclass();

*s = make<someclass>(1, 2, 3, 4);

otherclass *o = new otherclass();

*o = make<otherclass>(1, 2);
```

Ultimately, however, the big problem here is that you're starting off on the wrong foot. Chances are that for (at least) the next year or two, you should simply forget that C++ has `new` expressions at all. Feeling like you need it (especially in a case like this) is a fairly good sign that you haven't adapted to C++ very well yet, and are still trying to write Java.

Comment: "*Chances are that for (at least) the next year or two, you should simply forget that C++ has `new` expressions at all.*" +1

Comment: @user1000232: Yes -- it generally can and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Technically current `C++` is `C++11`.

Regardless, what you are doing is not possible without `C++11`. You can only brace initialize when you create the struct or array.

i.e

```
SomeClass temp = { 1,2,3,4 };
```

Edit: I need to look at its support in C++ but this seems to be possible in C99, by using something called [compound literals](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gcc/Compound-Literals.html)

```
SomeClass temp;

temp = ((SomeClass){1,2,3,4});
```

Edit2 - No cigar - [`source.cpp:9:31: warning: ISO C++ forbids compound-literals [-pedantic]`](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1i3qI5%240)

Seems like [someone else also had the same issue](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/13778/)

Comment: IS THERE NO WAY that I can initialize something with new and braces?...I will have to do A LOT of recoding of a lot of redundant things...

Comment: @user1000232 if you can use a temp variable, you can initialize the temp variable like this and then assign to `*temp`.